# Nested IF statement not giving todays date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with employee transactional data. Each row pertains to a hire or term event in column E. If column E is blank then that means it's a transfer.

[image]

As you can see, column D is blank and thats where this formula goes:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Terminate",E2)),C2,IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)>1,C3-1,today()))`

but when I enter it, this is the output:

[image]

row 2 column D should be todays date (4/21/23), but it's taking the day minus 1 from the next rows date? Any ideas?

Comment: `COUNTIF(B:B,B3)>1` is `TRUE`. What is the logic behind this `COUNTIF`, i.e. what are you trying to do in simple terms?

Comment: @BigBen row 2 is employee 7197, row 3 is a new employee 7198. I want it to essentially distinguish whether or not row 2 column B = row 3 column B. Since row 3 is the start of a new employee, row 2 column D should be today's date instead of 1 day before row 3 column C

Comment: Then use `B2=B3` instead of `COUNTIF(B:B,B2)`?

Comment: @BigBen hopefully that make sense. row 2 column D is subtracting the date from another employee (6/1/21 - one day). SInce row 3 is a different employee it shouldn't be doing that. it should just give today's date

Comment: does this work? 
        =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Terminate",E4)),C4,IF(B4<>B3,C5-1,TODAY()))

Comment: @HannahW I actually needed to change the <> to an = but that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get 5/31/21 because `COUNTIF(B:B,B3)>1` is `TRUE`.

If you want to return today's date for the last instance of the employee id (assuming they are grouped together), then compare `B2` to `B3`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Terminate",E2)),C2,IF(B2=B3,C3-1,TODAY()))
```